# How to overlay elements over video using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I'm building a website in Bootstrap 5 that features a fullscreen video on the homepage. I'm tried a few methods to make the navbar and title overlay the video but am struggling to get them to sit on top with the rest of the content sitting underneath the video.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
<section id="header">
        <div class="container-fluid edge">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                                <div class="navbar-nav">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <h1>This is the Overlay Title!</h1>
                    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                        <source src="assets/video/crowd_sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


#myVideo {
z-index: -1;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
object-fit: cover;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `z-index` of your video to -1 in order to move it in the background (assuming it has `position: absolute` already assigned)

```css
#myVideo {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rauberdaniel, that's worked fantastically! Do you know of a way I can have the overlay only apply to the navbar and title and have all other content display beneath the video?

Comment: You just have to specify the z-index for the different elements properly. E.g. give the video a z-index of 1 and the navbar and title a z-index of 2. Be aware though that z-index only works if the elements position is not the default `static`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index